# how to use loop inside a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
function radialTimer(callback) {
  var self = this;
  this.timerCallback = callback;
  this.seconds = 0;
  this.timeToMiddle = 0;
  this.count = 0;
  this.degrees = 0;
  this.increment = 0;
  this.interval = null;
  this.timerHTML = "<div class='ghost'></div><div class='n'></div><div class='slice'><div class='q'></div><div class='pie r'></div><div class='pie l'></div></div>";
  this.timerContainer = null;
  this.number = null;
  this.slice = null;
  this.pie = null;
  this.pieRight = null;
  this.pieLeft = null;

  this.init = function(e, s) {
    self.timerContainer = $("#" + e);
    self.timerContainer.html(self.timerHTML);
    self.number = self.timerContainer.find(".n");
    self.slice = self.timerContainer.find(".slice");
    self.pie = self.timerContainer.find(".pie");
    self.pieRight = self.timerContainer.find(".pie.r");
    self.pieLeft = self.timerContainer.find(".pie.l");

    self.start(s);
  }

  this.start = function(s) {
    self.seconds = s;
    self.increment = 360 / self.seconds;
    self.interval = window.setInterval(function() {
      if (self.count == Math.floor(self.seconds / 2)) {
        //need to stop clipping at exactly the right moment
        var timeToMiddle = ((self.seconds / 2) - self.count) * 1000;
        setTimeout(function() {
          self.slice.addClass("c");
          self.pieLeft.hide();

        }, timeToMiddle);
      }
      self.degrees += self.increment;
      self.pieRight.css({
        "transform": "rotate(" + self.degrees + "deg)"
      });

      self.number.html(self.seconds - self.count);
      self.count++;

      //Finished
      if (self.count > (self.seconds)) {
        clearInterval(self.interval);
        self.timerCallback();
        self.pieRight.css({
          "border": "15px solid white"
        });
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
  this.reset = function(t) {

    self.pie.show();
    self.slice.removeClass('c');
    self.timeToMiddle = 0;
    self.count = 0;
    self.degrees = 0;

    //move slices to original position without animation.
    self.pieRight.addClass('notransition');
    self.pieRight.css({
      "transform": "rotate(0deg)"
    });
    self.pieRight[0].offsetHeight; // Trigger a reflow
    self.pieRight.removeClass('notransition');

    Timer.start(t);
  }
}

var Timer;
var i = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {

  var callbackFunction = function() {
    Timer.reset(6);
    i += 1;
    $('h5').html('Question:' + i + '');

    document.getElementById("aq").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("bq").style.display = "";



  };
  Timer = new radialTimer(callbackFunction);
  Timer.init("timer", 6);



});
```

```css
.inputGroup {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.inputGroup label {
  padding: 12px 30px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  color: #3c454c;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: color 200ms ease-in;
  transition: color 200ms ease-in;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inputGroup label:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  background-color: #5562eb;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.inputGroup label:after {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  content: "";
  border: 2px solid #d1d7dc;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='32' height='32' viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.414 11L4 12.414l5.414 5.414L20.828 6.414 19.414 5l-10 10z' fill='%23fff' fill-rule='nonzero'/%3E%3C/svg%3E ");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 2px 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.inputGroup input:checked~label {
  color: #fff;
}

.inputGroup input:checked~label:before {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(56, 56, 1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(56, 56, 1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.inputGroup input:checked~label:after {
  background-color: #54e0c7;
  border-color: #54e0c7;
}

.inputGroup input {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  order: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.form {
  padding: 0 16px;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 150px auto;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 36px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

body {
  font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.form {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

code {
  background-color: #9aa3ac;
  padding: 0 8px;
}

</style><style>.radialtimer {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.radialtimer .n {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-family: "impact";
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.radialtimer .ghost {
  border: 15px rgb(255, 255, 255) double;
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.radialtimer .slice {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.radialtimer .slice.c {
  clip: rect(0px, 50px, 100px, 0px);
}

.radialtimer .slice .pie {
  border: 15px rgb(255, 255, 255) solid;
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  clip: rect(0px, 50px, 100px, 0px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  z-index: 1;
}

.radialtimer .slice .pie.r {
  clip: rect(0px, 100px, 100px, 50px);
}

.radialtimer .slice .pie.notransition {
  transition: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <style>

  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class='radialtimer' id='timer'></div>
  <h5> Question:1 </h5>

  <form class="form" id="aq1">


    <h2> question number 1?</h2>
    <div class="inputGroup">
      <input id="radio1" name="radio" type="radio" />
      <label for="radio1">Option 1 </label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputGroup">
      <input id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio" />
      <label for="radio2">Option 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputGroup">
      <input id="radio3" name="radio" type="radio" />
      <label for="radio3">Option 3 </label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputGroup">
      <input id="radio4" name="radio" type="radio" />
      <label for="radio4">Option 4 </label>
    </div>

  </form>
  <form class="form" id="bq2" style="display: none;">


    <h2>Question number 2?</h2>
    <div class="inputGroup">
      <input id="radio5" name="radio" type="radio" />
      <label for="radio5">Option 1 </label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputGroup">
      <input id="radio6" name="radio" type="radio" />
      <label for="radio6">Option 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputGroup">
      <input id="radio7" name="radio" type="radio" />
      <label for="radio7">Option 3 </label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputGroup">
      <input id="radio8" name="radio" type="radio" />
      <label for="radio8">Option 4</label>
    </div>

  </form>

  <form class="form" id="cq" style="display: none;">


    <h2>Question number 3?</h2>
    <div class="inputGroup">
      <input id="radio5" name="radio" type="radio" />
      <label for="radio5">Option 1 </label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputGroup">
      <input id="radio6" name="radio" type="radio" />
      <label for="radio6">Option 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputGroup">
      <input id="radio7" name="radio" type="radio" />
      <label for="radio7">Option 3 </label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputGroup">
      <input id="radio8" name="radio" type="radio" />
      <label for="radio8">Option 4</label>
    </div>

  </form>







</body>

</html>
```

the above code is working correctly.But i have 5 form elements of id(aq,bq,cq,dq,eq) all set to display none except aq.when it comes to timer reset to 3, i can able to change aq as display none and bq to display,but i need to proceed with  cq to display and hide the bq when timer gets reset, and again when timer reset,i need dq to show, and cq to hide, its  for a quiz.

Answer (score 1):

```
let ids= ["aq","bq" ... ];
```

then instead of you

```
document.getElementById("aq").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("bq").style.display = "";
```

use the i variable:

```
document.getElementById(ids[i-1]).style.display = "none";
document.getElementById(ids[i]).style.display = "";
```